# Explaining inheritance in Python

Tags: python

I was going through some Python code and found this code snippet

```
class A(object):
    ...
    def add_commands(self, cmd):
        self.commands.append(cmd)
    ...

class B(A):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.commands = []
    ...
```

Now, because of inheritance, B will have access to the method 'add_commands'. What surprises me is that even though class A does not know about the list 'commands' this program compiles just fine forget the method execution on the object B which also turns out to be fine. The only time it errors out is when we create an object of the class A and call the method 'add_commands'. I understand that its the 'self' keyword which is saving us here. This would not be the case in a programming language like C++ as the compilation itself fails.

This brings me to my question - How should one approach inheritance in a programming language like Python? Considering the above example, is that the right way to design a class in Python?

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to design your code this way. Why don't we just put `add_commands` in `B` if we can't use it in `A`?

Comment: There *are* situations where you will want to define things in a child to be manipulated in a parent method, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Python is a interpreted language, scripts are parsed during runtime.

Comment: Very little compile-time checking is done in python.  You can get away with most everything short of syntax errors.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you post that as an answer and explain the cases that you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the question of *how to approach inheritance in Python* is too broad to be answered in a single post (I'd start checking the official docs). What I would like to add is the following:

Don´t apply the exact same design principles of inheritance you would apply on a compiled language (like C++ or Java) to Python. One of the biggest strengths of Python is its flexibility (which is a dangerous, but extremely powerful tool if used correctly).

Python is not reporting any errors in the code you posted above because *it is not wrong* from a Python point of view (and obviously because Python is interpreted and not compiled). The *pythonic* way to do things is not usually what is recommended (or even possible) in other languages.

You may find yourself in a situation (as has been pointed above in the comments) where you want to define attributes in a child to be accessed from its parent methods. I tried to come up with an example with the hope that it'll be helpful.

Imagine you have two classes representing two different resources (databases, files, etc) `FirstResource` and `SecondResource`. Each resource has its own methods, but both of them have structural similarities that cause some methods to have the same implementation, and those operations deal with some attribute `resource_attr`. The initialization logic for `resource_attr` is different for each resource.

Maybe this could be an implementation option to solve this situation:

```
class BaseResource(object):

    def common_operation_a(self):

        # Use self.resource_attr to do Operation A

    def common_operation_b(self):

        # Use self.resource_attr to do Operation B

class FirstResource(BaseResource):

    def __init__(self):

        self.resource_attr = initialize_attr_for_first_resource()

    # ... FirstResource specific operations

class SecondResource(BaseResource):

    def __init__(self):

        self.resource_attr = initialize_attr_for_second_resource()

    # ... SecondResource specific methods
```

Then you could use this implementation as follows:

```
# Create resources objects

first_resource_instance = FirstResource()
second_resource_instance = SecondResource()

# The resources share the implementation of Operation A

first_resource_instance.common_operation_a()
second_resource_instance.common_operation_a()

# The following implementations are resource-specific

first_resource_instance.some_operation_c()
second_resource_instance.some_operation_d()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in Python uses the same paradigms as Object oriented inheritance.  Being an interpreted language, there is a lot you can get away with, but that doesn't mean your classes shouldn't be designed with the same care as if you were writing compiled languages like Java and C++.